# What is the triple question mark mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Looking at some JS code [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html#making-our-code-testable) shows the snippet...

```js
  assert.deepEqual(
    gen.next(),
    { done: false, value: ??? },
    'incrementAsync should return a Promise that will resolve after 1 second'
  )
```

My question is: What is the `???` symbol mean? Any docs for it? I assume it's some kind of "anything" placeholder, but a google search did not pull any results for it.

Comment: Given that the previous code sample in that documentation shows various different values for `{ value: ... }` and that the entire section is talking you through the difficulty of testing that value: it doesn't mean anything and is not actual code.

Answer (score 1):

That's invalid syntax (the ternary is just one question mark and the null assertion is just two), so I assume you're right that it's a placeholder for any value.